# I'm trying to convert order into PDF using Dompdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm actually working on a Laravel 8 marketplace and i want to convert orders into pdf. Instead getting a PDF page, i get redirected to the orders table.

Here are the controller functions

```
class PdfController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function view_pdf($id){

        Session::put('id', $id);
        try{
            $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper')->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_orders_data_to_html());

            return $pdf->stream();
        }
        catch(\ Exception $e){
            return redirect('/orders')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function convert_orders_data_to_html()
    {

        $orders = Order::where('id',Session::get('id'))->get();

        foreach($orders as $order){
            $first_name = $order->first_name;
            $last_name = $order->last_name;
            $tel = $order->tel;
            $region = $order->region;
            $city = $order->city;
            $hood = $order->hood;
            $street = $order->street;
            $date = $order->created_at;
        }

        $orders-> transform( function ($order, $key ) {
                $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
                return $order;
            });

        $output = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="frontend/css/style.css">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="thead">
                                <tr class="text-left">
                                    <th>Client Name : '.$first_name && $last_name.'<br> Client Address : '.$region && $city && $hood && $street.' <br> Date : '.$date.'</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="thead-primary">
                                <tr class="text-center">
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Product name</th>
                                    <th>Product size</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>';

        foreach($orders as $order){
            foreach($order->cart->items as $item){

                $output .= '<tr class="text-center">
                                <td class="image-prod"><img src="storage/product_images/'.$item['prod_image'].'" alt="" style = "height: 80px; width: 80px;"></td>
                                <td class="product-name">
                                    <h3>'.$item['prod_name'].'</h3>
                                </td>
                                <td class="product-name">
                                    <h3>'.$item['size'].'</h3>
                                </td>
                                <td class="price">$ '.$item['prod_price'].' XAF</td>
                                <td class="qty">'.$item['prod_qty'].'</td>
                                <td class="total">$ '.$item['prod_price']*$item['prod_qty'].'</td>
                            </tr><!-- END TR-->
                            </tbody>';

            }

            $totalPrice = $order->cart->totalPrice;

        }

        $output .='</table>';

        $output .='<table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead">
                            <tr class="text-center">
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>$ '.$totalPrice.'</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>';


        return $output;



    }
}
```

The view_pdf function is supposed to either bring me to the PDF page if the "try" is made or rerender the orders page as said in the "catch". But it gets me directly to the "catch

Here is the route for pdf coversion

```
// PDF conversion
Route::get('/view_pdf/{id}', [PdfController::class, 'view_pdf']);
```

Can someone help me out and tell me what i'm i doing wrong please?

Comment: You're getting redirected from the exception due to some issue; print the exception $e message and you'll know !

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.. you should create a mypdf.blade.php file also

```
$data = $this->convert_orders_data_to_html()
      
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data);

    return $pdf->download('yourpdf.pdf');
```

you can read tutorial to this link this is very simpe
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-pdf-laravel-8-generate-pdf-file-using-dompdfexample.html#google_vignette